# invalid column index error with Prepare statement

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am getting `invalid column index` for following prepared statement.
Here is my code

```
// Excluding some unnecessary code
counter = 1;
if (rsTableNames.next()) 
{
    // Creating Query for prepared statement
    String getCode = "select * from ( select c_name from " 
          + rsTableNames.getString(1)+ " where lower(c_name) like ?%'";
    while (rsTableNames.next()) 
    {
      getCode += " union select c_name from " + 
      rsTableNames.getString(1)+ " where lower(c_name) like ?%'";
      counter++;
    }
    getCode += " ) where rownum <= " + maxRecords;
        // Now  The getCode contains 3 place holders ie ?           
    pst = con.prepareStatement(getCode);
    String param = "'" + query.toLowerCase();

    for(int i=1;i<=counter;i++)
    {
        pst.setString(i,param);  // when i=3 exception is thrown
    }
}
```

I am getting the exception when `i` becomes `3` though the query contains 3 place holders.
**EDIT (HINT):** I think the problem is with the `'` which is creating havoc. How can we escape it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether it's the cause of the problem, but I don't think parameters work quite the way you think they do when it comes to quoting. You're still adding quotes in your code *after* each parameter and as the start of your parameter. I suspect you just want:

```
rsTableNames.getString(1)+ " where lower(c_name) like ?";
```

in each place, then:

```
String param = query.toLowerCase() + "%";
```

It's possible that due to quote parsing, this will fix the issue - I think your middle parameter is being deemed to be part of a big *literal*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it, it removed the error but it creates wrong query. I guess `'` is required for `like` clause. I think I need to escape `'` but dont know how.

Comment: @Ajinkya What do you mean by "wrong query"? Please give examples of what you're getting in terms of results vs what you expected to get.

Comment: @John: It creates query with `.. where like query%` (It removes `'` from `like` clause which is required. ) so it gives zero result thoguh there are some records in database.I think clause should be somewhat like `..where like 'query%'`.

Comment: @Ajinkya: Phew - I was running out of things I could think of. Glad it's all sorted!

Comment: Sorry I made you think out of the box :)

Answer (score 0):

are you sure there are 3 ? in the sql? try print the entire preparedStatement in the for loop.

I suspect that the many loops you have here might not have worked like you expected, and in the end there were only 2 parameters in the preparedStatement.

What exception was thrown?
From Java API:
Throws:
SQLException - if parameterIndex does not correspond to a parameter marker in the SQL statement; if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement

also, if you share the con connection, and the con.preparedStatement instance, make sure you have close each properly

Comment: Everything is in place. The problem is with the `'`.